# How to create example data set from private data (replacing variable names and levels with uninformative place holders)?

Tags: r

To provide a reproducible example of an approach, a data set must often be provided.  Instead of building an example data set, I wish to use some of my own data.  However this data can not be released.  I wish to replace variable (column) names and factor levels with uninformative place holders (eg. V1....V5, L1....L5).

***Is an automated way to do this available?***

Ideally, this would be done in R, taking in a data.frame and producing this anonymous data.frame.

With such a data set, simply search and replace variable names in your script and you have a publicly releasable reproducible example.

Such a process may increase the inclusion of appropriate data in reproducible examples and even the inclusion of reproducible examples in questions, comments and bug reports.

Comment: I'd suggest it may also be important to anonymize the data itself, perhaps by rescaling by (x-mean)/sd or to a unif(0,1), depending on the data set.  One would have to keep in mind the purpose of the data set, as either of these specific suggestions could hide important features.

Comment: Rescaling should work.  Maybe just normalization.  I still need the structure to be present.

Comment: I added a solution that avoids loops, tags levels with variable names and avoid loops.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't know whether there *was* a function to automate this, but *now* there is ;)

```
## A function to anonymise columns in 'colIDs' 
##    colIDs can be either column names or integer indices
anonymiseColumns <- function(df, colIDs) {
    id <- if(is.character(colIDs)) match(colIDs, names(df)) else colIDs
    for(id in colIDs) {
        prefix <- sample(LETTERS, 1)
        suffix <- as.character(as.numeric(as.factor(df[[id]])))
        df[[id]] <- paste(prefix, suffix, sep="")
    }
    names(df)[id] <- paste("V", id, sep="")
    df
}

## A data.frame containing sensitive information
df <- data.frame(
    name = rep(readLines(file.path(R.home("doc"), "AUTHORS"))[9:13], each=2),
    hiscore = runif(10, 99, 100),
    passwd = replicate(10, paste(sample(c(LETTERS, letters), 9), collapse="")))

## Anonymise it
df2 <- anonymiseColumns(df, c(1,3))

## Check that it worked
> head(df, 3)
           name  hiscore    passwd
1 Douglas Bates 99.96714 ROELIAncz
2 Douglas Bates 99.07243 gDOLNMyVe
3 John Chambers 99.55322 xIVPHDuEW    

> head(df2, 3)
  name hiscore  V3
1   Q1 99.96714 V8
2   Q1 99.07243 V2
3   Q2 99.55322 V9
```

Comment: One way to extend this would be to write out a translator or key, i.e. a file of the original factors and their new anonymous versions. `"Douglas Bates"|"Q1"`. Useful for when you give the data to someone else, but want to compare results back to yours perhaps?

Comment: I hope you don't usually store passwords in plain text like that :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is my version of the function.
Advantages: no for loops, level labels match variable labels, can be applied to any df, ordered variable names beyond 26 letters, normalization of numeric variables...

Thanks go to:
@Tyler Rinker for a solution to using column names in apply functions &
@Josh O'Brien for his response to this question

[It is available here as a gist.](https://gist.github.com/2599463)

The data from @Josh O'Brien with a non factor variable

```
   df <- data.frame(
  name = rep(readLines(file.path(R.home("doc"), "AUTHORS"))[9:13], each=2),
  hiscore = runif(10, 99, 100),
  passwd = replicate(10, paste(sample(c(LETTERS, letters), 9), collapse="")))

df$passwd<-as.character(df$passwd)
```

The function

```
anonym<-function(df){
  if(length(df)>26){
    LETTERS<-replicate(floor(length(df)/26),{LETTERS<-c(LETTERS, paste(LETTERS, LETTERS, sep=""))})
    }
    names(df)<-paste(LETTERS[1:length(df)])

    level.id.df<-function(df){
        level.id<-function(i){
      if(class(df[,i])=="factor" | class(df[,i])=="character"){
        column<-paste(names(df)[i],as.numeric(as.factor(df[,i])), sep=".")}else if(is.numeric(df[,i])){
          column<-df[,i]/mean(df[,i], na.rm=T)}else{column<-df[,i]}
          return(column)}
      DF <- data.frame(sapply(seq_along(df), level.id))
      names(DF) <- names(df)
      return(DF)}
    df<-level.id.df(df)
    return(df)}

anonym(df)
```

The results:

```
    A                 B    C
1  A.1  1.00492190370171  C.8
2  A.1 0.997214883153158  C.2
3  A.2  1.00532434407094  C.5
4  A.2  1.00015775550051  C.6
5  A.3 0.998947207241593  C.3
6  A.3 0.998083738806433  C.4
7  A.5  1.00322085765279  C.7
8  A.5 0.995853096468764  C.1
9  A.4 0.998662338687036 C.10
10 A.4  0.99761387471706  C.9
```

Answer (score 14):

If all you want to do is replace the column names with anonymous labels and likewise for levels of factors, yes. First some dummy data to use as the example

```
dat <- data.frame(top_secret1 = rnorm(10), top_secret2 = runif(10),
                  top_secret3 = factor(sample(3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                                       labels = paste("Person", 1:3, sep = "")))
```

To replace the column names do:

```
dat2 <- dat
colnames(dat2) <- paste("Variable", seq_len(ncol(dat2)), sep = "")
```

Which gives

```
> head(dat2)
   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
1 -0.4858656 0.4846700   Person3
2  0.2660125 0.1727989   Person1
3  0.1595297 0.6413984   Person2
4  1.1952239 0.1892749   Person3
5  0.3914285 0.6235119   Person2
6  0.3752015 0.7057372   Person3
```

Next change the levels

```
foo <- function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x)) {
        levels(x) <- sample(LETTERS, length(levels(x)))
    }
    x
}
dat3 <- data.frame(lapply(dat2, foo))
```

which gives

```
> head(dat3)
   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
1 -0.4858656 0.4846700         K
2  0.2660125 0.1727989         G
3  0.1595297 0.6413984         O
4  1.1952239 0.1892749         K
5  0.3914285 0.6235119         O
6  0.3752015 0.7057372         K
```

`foo()` is just a simple wrapper to a function that passed a vector checks if it is a factor, if it is, change the levels to a vector of random letters of appropriate length, then return the vector.

We can wrap this into a function to do all the changes requested

```
anonymise <- function(df, colString = "Variable", rowString = "Sample") {
    foo <- function(x) {
        if(is.factor(x)) {
            levels(x) <- sample(LETTERS, length(levels(x)))
        }
        x
    }
    ## replace the variable names
    colnames(df) <- paste(colString, seq_len(ncol(df)), sep = "")
    ## fudge any factor levels
    df <- data.frame(lapply(df, foo))
    ## replace rownames
    rownames(df) <- paste(rowString, seq_len(nrow(df)), sep = "")
    ## return
    df
}
```

In use this gives

```
> anonymise(dat)
           Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
Sample1  -0.48586557 0.4846700         F
Sample2   0.26601253 0.1727989         L
Sample3   0.15952973 0.6413984         N
Sample4   1.19522395 0.1892749         F
Sample5   0.39142851 0.6235119         N
Sample6   0.37520154 0.7057372         F
Sample7   1.18440762 0.7355211         F
Sample8   0.03605239 0.3924925         L
Sample9  -0.64078219 0.4579347         N
Sample10 -1.39680109 0.9047227         L
```

Comment: that's very nice, but only works for variables that are stored as a factor. If a character, the function returns the non-anonymised values. Also, it doesn't work when the factor variabels have more than 26 levels.