# How to create an example (anonymous) R script to provide a reproducible example?

Tags: r

This is related to:
[How to create example data set from private data (replacing variable names and levels with uninformative place holders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454973/how-to-create-example-data-set-from-private-data-replacing-variable-names-and-l)
Which stems from :
[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

I have come to realize that having an anonymous data set (were the data and labels are uninformative but consistent with the original data) is half the battle of producing a reproducible example (for questions or bug reporting) from script and data you can not share (eg. proprietary information, unpublished findings, etc.).

Any suggestions as how to automate the translation of a script so that it matches the variables in the anonymous data frame created using one of the answers provided at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454973/how-to-create-example-data-set-from-private-data-replacing-variable-names-and-l%29)

This may be more of a challenge than it is worth, but if it went into widespread use (say as a package), it could reduce the occurrence of questions and bug reports that do not have a reproducible example.

Comment: There are so many example datasets in R, I would be surprised if not one of them matched, at least to some extent, your scenario.

Comment: It, of course, depends on the type of data. If you have a data set based on means and deviations around the mean, one option could be either to use `rnorm` or bootstrap on the values and change the axis labels to something generic. This is not a new trick in StackExchange.

Comment: As indicated, the data is no longer the problem.  It is matching the new anonymous data to a complex script that is the problem (mapping all the new variable names).