# How to calculate population prevalence in R using data.table

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I hoping someone can point me in the right direction of how I can calculate a population prevalence proportion without having to do it in excel.

I´m currently working on a project that requires me to find the annual prevalence for eating *fruit* stratified by sex, agegr. To complicate matters unique id's can eat *fruit* from different kinds of *fruitgroups* but two of the four fruits belong to the same fruitgroup and therefor can only be counted once per id.

To further complicate the issue I need to report the prevalence by

- total fruits per year per 1000 in the population,
- per individual fruits per year per 1000,
- per the fruitgroup that has the two fruit in,
- by age
- by sex

Here is my dataset - you might have figured out that due to restrictions on my database I had to change the actual values - special thanks to [this reproduce code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16532098/2997696) and to [this answer on how to make your data anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455661/2997696)

```
    #### Data ####
require(data.table) 
anonDT <- data.table(structure(list(id = c("E1998", "E2308", "E1421", "E676", "E5061","E4225", "E2600", "E658", "E2331", "E982", "E4790", "E408", "E1048","E3937", "E4554", "E3357", "E2637", "E178", "E3734", "E1217","E3771", "E1954", "E4928", "E3566", "E1106", "E3835", "E1505","E668", "E4083", "E3066", "E3356", "E4910", "E2801", "E1074","E5097", "E610", "E995", "E1001", "E3824", "E3427", "E3885","E648", "E1986", "E4777", "E2546", "E909", "E1954", "E634", "E2602","E531", "E67", "E2418", "E3863", "E4266", "E196", "E657", "E1516","E4722", "E3077", "E3732", "E1556", "E112", "E924", "E2801","E2742", "E3362", "E1880", "E3645", "E3357", "E2519", "E2450","E5162", "E1483", "E3846", "E4539", "E2452", "E282", "E4604","E226", "E5043", "E3909", "E88", "E51", "E1925", "E2776", "E3835","E4746", "E1631", "E4052", "E1128", "E220", "E1390", "E4908","E1385", "E1003", "E5181", "E3835", "E4910", "E3240", "E4380","E3357", "E963", "E706", "E5142", "E2869", "E3839", "E5271","E2584", "E194", "E4366", "E2621", "E932", "E1104", "E1964","E928", "E4377", "E1418", "E2940", "E3420", "E3958", "E4130","E790", "E3667", "E934", "E3356", "E5203", "E3835", "E3356","E3297", "E5203", "E4380", "E668", "E2856", "E4502", "E1054","E3644", "E4641", "E5204", "E2597", "E4432", "E2716", "E2422","E1964", "E1327", "E2028", "E2727", "E1868", "E638", "E88", "E4892","E706", "E5147", "E3130", "E4099", "E4239", "E341", "E593", "E4746","E2291", "E2240", "E2481", "E3846", "E2602", "E1673", "E4772","E2140", "E5024", "E1137", "E2182", "E4366", "E2386", "E648","E3118", "E8", "E2813", "E3422", "E3982", "E2", "E2940", "E2035","E4746", "E5134", "E4380", "E4615", "E1372", "E2249", "E1954","E2418", "E1122", "E3485", "E934", "E3611", "E2665", "E2961","E2108", "E4432", "E2447", "E3413", "E531", "E1751"),
                                sex = structure(c(1L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("male", "female"), class = "factor"),group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("fruitgr1","fruitgr2", "fruitgr3"), class = "factor"),
                                subgroup = structure(c(4L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L,4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L,3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L,1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L,1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L,4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L,4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L,2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L,2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L,4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L,4L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("apple", "orange", "banana","kiwi"), class = "factor"),
                                agegr = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L,2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L,3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L,1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L,1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L,2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L,3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,1L, 2L), .Label = c("19-24", "25-49", "50+"), class = "factor"),year = c(2004, 2007, 2008, 2006, 2008, 2007, 2008, 2007,2007, 2007, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2004,2008, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2005, 2006, 2005, 2005,2006, 2007, 2006, 2008, 2008, 2006, 2004, 2004, 2007, 2005,2008, 2008, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2005, 2008,2008, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007,2008, 2008, 2005, 2007, 2007, 2005, 2008, 2007, 2004, 2008,2007, 2008, 2005, 2005, 2008, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2005,2004, 2008, 2004, 2007, 2005, 2008, 2004, 2008, 2008, 2006,2008, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2005, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2007,2007, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2008, 2004, 2008, 2008, 2006, 2005,2004, 2007, 2006, 2004, 2005, 2004, 2006, 2005, 2008, 2004,2007, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2005, 2007, 2007,2006, 2005, 2008, 2004, 2008, 2007, 2008, 2004, 2008, 2007,2007, 2004, 2004, 2008, 2004, 2007, 2008, 2005, 2007, 2005,2008, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2005, 2007,2006, 2008, 2005, 2006, 2008, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007,2007, 2006, 2008, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2005, 2008, 2007, 2004,2005, 2006, 2007, 2006, 2008, 2006, 2008, 2004, 2006, 2008,2007, 2004, 2008, 2008, 2004, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2006,2004, 2004)), .Names = c("id", "sex", "group", "subgroup","agegr", "year"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-200L)))
```

And the population data is here:

```
#### Population data ####
populDT <- data.table(structure(list(year = 2004:2008, total = c(210696L, 216192L,223472L, 230629L, 233625L), men = c(104770L, 108390L, 113597L,117629L, 118275L), women = c(105926L, 107802L, 109875L, 113000L,115350L), agegrp1 = c(25721L, 25558L, 25933L, 27457L, 28083L), agegrp2 = c(104933L, 107935L, 111796L, 114852L, 115102L),agegrp3 = c(80042L, 82699L, 85743L, 88320L, 90440L)), .Names = c("year","total", "men", "women", "agegrp1", "agegrp2", "agegrp3"), sorted = "year", class = c("data.table","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), key='year'))
```

I have managed to get all the relevant prevalence counts into a single data.table

```
allcount <- anonDT[,.N, keyby=list(year,agegr,sex,group,subgroup,id)][,.N,by=list(year,agegr,sex,group,subgroup)]
allcount
```

as well as making several subsets of data.tables including the counts I need.

As for my questions,

1. is there a simple way of calculating the prevalence proportion (formula is 1000*those who eat fruit/total population) inside the data.table for all the relevant stratifications and groups.
2. Would I need to merge the populDT with the allcount?
3. If so what would be the best way forward
4. And as a bonus conundrum what would be the best way to create publication table/graph from the data.table?

Thank you all in advance... as this is my first time posting I hope I've done everything correctly :)

Here is a data.table of the almost desired outcome. I only managed to get it in this state by using data.frame not table. To be more precise I created count variables for all and then used aggregate to get it into shape

```
### first using max ### 
prevAN <- aggregate(anon[,7:17], 
              by = list(anon$year,anon$id,anon$group, anon$subgroup), 
              FUN = max) 
### and then by sum ###
prevAN1 <- aggregate(prevAN[,5:15], 
               by = list(prevAN$year), 
               FUN = sum)


### the count dataset ###
DT2 <- data.table(structure(list(year = c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008), count = c(865,1095, 1355, 1602, 1749), men = c(470, 616, 748, 863, 946), women = c(395,479, 607, 739, 803), agegr1 = c(141, 220, 272, 316, 385), agegr2 = c(552,657, 826, 1001, 1040), agegr3 = c(172, 218, 257, 285, 324), c_fruitgr2 = c(703,910, 1130, 1304, 1451), c_banana = c(153, 397, 618, 798, 950),c_kiwi = c(550, 513, 512, 506, 501), c_apple = c(121, 114,97, 110, 112), c_orange = c(41, 71, 128, 188, 186), total = c(210696L,216192L, 223472L, 230629L, 233625L), men.1 = c(104770L, 108390L,113597L, 117629L, 118275L),
                             women.1 = c(105926L, 107802L,109875L, 113000L, 115350L), agegrp1 = c(25721L, 25558L, 25933L,27457L, 28083L), agegrp2 = c(104933L, 107935L, 111796L, 114852L,115102L), agegrp3 = c(80042L, 82699L, 85743L, 88320L, 90440L)), .Names = c("year", "count", "men", "women", "agegr1","agegr2", "agegr3", "c_fruitgr2", "c_banana", "c_kiwi", "c_apple","c_orange", "total", "men.1", "women.1", "agegrp1", "agegrp2","agegrp3"), sorted = "year", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), key='year'))
```

When I get to this stage I need to calculate the prevalence from the figures in each year. I would do this using a data.frame by simply doing the following:

```
total.prev <- DF2$count*1000/DF2$total
```

Back to the questions at hand, firstly I love how fast data.table works and even though I am able to roughly get where I need to go with my data using aggregate I would like to learn how I can do this in data.table as I have a feeling that it is quicker and more productive.

Secondly there is the issue of the calculation, calculating within a data.table or between data.tables.

And thirdly there is the issue of graphs and tables for publication but that might be a second post.

**UPDATE**
I have figured out a way to calculate the prevelance within the data.table by doing the following

```
DT2[,':='(p1= count*1000/total,
        pM= men*1000/men.1,
        pW= women*1000/women.1,
        pA1= agegr1*1000/agegrp1,
        pA2= agegr2*1000/agegrp2,
        pA3= agegr3*1000/agegrp3,
        pFgr2= c_fruitgr2*1000/total,
        pB= c_banana*1000/total,
        pK= c_kiwi*1000/total,
        pA= c_apple*1000/total,
        pO= c_orange*1000/total),]

DT2<-round(DT2, 2)  # to round the prevalence numbers
```

Again if someone has anything simpler to offer :)

Comment: fix your `anonDT` dput - it's not working

Comment: separately, I recommend creating example data that's simple enough that you can show the desired outcome - personally, I don't understand what exactly you want

Comment: Dataset should be working now. As for creating a simpler example data, I'll get on that now.

Comment: @eddi sorry it took so long but I´ve managed to create a clearer example - I hope.

Comment: The data in the question is still very complex, and you're asking four questions. Please simplify it (you can generally communicate what you're trying to do with built-in datasets) and split this out into separate SO questions.