# Comparing interaction effect plots involving continuous variables from ggplot2 vs. base R using the effects package

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot interaction effects on my data set. I cannot share the full data set due to confidentiality reasons, but I have added the output of the `effect()` function, which can be substituted into the plot functions to reproduce my results

The interaction effect is between two continuous variables, `varP` and `varL`. The model is a binomial probit glm. I am using the `effects()` package.

Calling base R `plot()` yields the following chart:

```
plot(effect("varL:varP", hx.x), multiline = TRUE)
```

[image]

Calling `ggplot` yields an error, because `ggplot2` cannot deal with continuous variables (`Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to linetype`). So I decided to use `cut()` to transform the continuous into a categorical variable and redo the regression. Calling `ggplot` now yields the following plot:

```
ggplot(data.frame(effect("varL:varP_range", hx.x1))) + 
 geom_line(aes(varL,fit,linetype=varP_range)) + 
 theme_bw() + 
 geom_point(aes(varL,fit, shape = varP_range), size = 4)
```

[image]

The `effect()` call results in the following data frame:

```
structure(list(varL = c(0, 4900000, 9800000, 1.5e+07, 2e+07, 
0, 4900000, 9800000, 1.5e+07, 2e+07, 0, 4900000, 9800000, 1.5e+07, 
2e+07, 0, 4900000, 9800000, 1.5e+07, 2e+07, 0, 4900000, 9800000, 
1.5e+07, 2e+07, 0, 4900000, 9800000, 1.5e+07, 2e+07, 0, 4900000, 
9800000, 1.5e+07, 2e+07, 0, 4900000, 9800000, 1.5e+07, 2e+07), 
    varP_range = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L), .Label = c("(0,0.1]", "(0.1,0.2]", "(0.2,0.3]", 
    "(0.3,0.4]", "(0.4,0.5]", "(0.5,0.6]", "(0.6,0.7]", "(0.7,0.8]", 
    NA), class = "factor"), fit = c(0.0493753018091432, 0.0674980435061065, 
    0.0903776022141578, 0.120475525568566, 0.155489425305936, 
    0.0137978311572348, 0.0146948327184384, 0.0156415523658014, 
    0.0167030042368772, 0.0177811545669692, 0.0283241226002015, 
    0.0320688611660079, 0.0362132772188478, 0.0410808356583781, 
    0.0462488565292175, 0.0376893470992477, 0.0434689290038736, 
    0.0499436899670642, 0.0576329205782917, 0.0658761148111993, 
    0.0461027343009466, 0.0491516310196363, 0.0523594626652533, 
    0.0559432088894986, 0.0595689358953948, 0.0271243286792884, 
    0.0288090021916312, 0.0305797680715237, 0.0325565879397662, 
    0.0345556259933517, 0.0585874566843392, 0.0695486360371181, 
    0.0820248510196267, 0.0970343941431089, 0.113280038210583, 
    0.0209075509863267, 0.0315251673839061, 0.046253681947139, 
    0.0674584535698224, 0.0942769896468577), se = c(0.026293040668674, 
    0.0305781859107515, 0.0540612604209606, 0.0833019722980397, 
    0.112487542810938, 0.0338534463222995, 0.0398771851800222, 
    0.0731653210576088, 0.113913900015802, 0.15437353282528, 
    0.0409108254231718, 0.0511475671899819, 0.0972355260310069, 
    0.152187250282481, 0.206403037601197, 0.0130040830190118, 
    0.0163131582968098, 0.03036212612247, 0.0472104967827754, 
    0.0638665398985353, 0.00832820196917705, 0.0121268883535081, 
    0.0232740805148284, 0.0361535949146859, 0.0487814483071773, 
    0.0113362224665359, 0.0147098330114556, 0.027542020584634, 
    0.0427882020481342, 0.057830481511906, 0.01601220706873, 
    0.0215340145342622, 0.040911260287911, 0.0636748713064177, 
    0.0860732173940343, 0.0419361989774607, 0.0474273262485864, 
    0.085507397635156, 0.132979171779259, 0.180309829530109), 
    lower = c(0.0443332267166309, 0.0600183728153565, 0.0743144400165266, 
    0.0907939516369112, 0.108668209187463, 0.0116238722892657, 
    0.012023490450893, 0.0108135425488573, 0.00937570172867644, 
    0.00809811278621186, 0.0235056239743921, 0.025500658500369, 
    0.0234608868503482, 0.0208470526400479, 0.0184481609874694, 
    0.0356438216686479, 0.0406013691901053, 0.0441057429680943, 
    0.0477084891588961, 0.0512971927819841, 0.0445466712620454, 
    0.0467806376034436, 0.0476567944606461, 0.048393808464277, 
    0.0490625016612481, 0.0257635103540086, 0.0269634191042765, 
    0.0270321095726769, 0.0269061995593561, 0.0267392100653416, 
    0.0550074959164803, 0.0640838876027606, 0.0705422656571929, 
    0.0773047979652944, 0.0841065921246788, 0.017106637503393, 
    0.025481438787035, 0.0321633667203674, 0.0395762352261805, 
    0.0476311065775831), upper = c(0.0548650233126245, 0.0756784493915628, 
    0.108885802402636, 0.156404820719125, 0.213976690522108, 
    0.0163138248731072, 0.0178616891841985, 0.0222128708020368, 
    0.0284614557616305, 0.0359832219741959, 0.0339378335208811, 
    0.039975201853988, 0.0541535055907615, 0.0749340625856128, 
    0.100655675600276, 0.0398297048294564, 0.0464977933470156, 
    0.0563819985882714, 0.0691131684577491, 0.0834778881744663, 
    0.0477021593328273, 0.0516176358055639, 0.0574233019439704, 
    0.0643924091986213, 0.0717620710757599, 0.0285446055381808, 
    0.0307584171780848, 0.0345046440925246, 0.0391516285886827, 
    0.0441582201173176, 0.062347826961093, 0.0753653653841884, 
    0.0948621519669373, 0.120230399782042, 0.149038245196167, 
    0.0254001895885684, 0.0387079476679479, 0.0649209421145592, 
    0.108535107340218, 0.16815843130232)), .Names = c("varL", 
"varP_range", "fit", "se", "lower", "upper"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40"), class = "data.frame")
```

My questions are:

**1) How does `effect()` from the `effects` package transform the continuous into a categorical variable? How would this be replicated with `ggplot()`?**

**2) What is the reason that the lines in the base R plot all intersect at the same coordinate?**

Comment: It's going to be much easier to answer this question with a reproducible example: unless the answer is easy/at the tip of someone's tongue, it's far easier to go through the example and see what's going on than to think through it on an abstract level. Also note that you're using the `effects()` package ...

Comment: OK, I will add the output of the effects function

Comment: I still can't replicate this. I save your data frame as `eff`: neither `plot(eff)` nor `effects:::plot.eff(eff)` works to give me your plot.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454973/how-to-create-example-data-set-from-private-data-replacing-variable-names-and-l give some suggestions about generating a reproducible example for confidential data ...

Comment: I realized that `ggplot` uses dataframes, while `plot` uses the original effect object. However, it is difficult to provide, as it has more than 18MB. I will try my best to create a better example.

Comment: did you really post the output of `dput(effect("varL:varP", hx.x))` ? that should have worked. (`dput()` should output a text version of the effect object that can be read back in to exactly recreate the original ...)

Comment: No it was `dput(data.frame(effect("varL:varP", hx.x)))` - I also tried to apply `dput` directly to `effect()` but the object is 18MB large, so the `dput` output is too large to be shared here

Comment: OK, then you probably need to go back one step and construct a reproducible example. How about taking a 0.1% sample, making sure the same behaviour still occurs, and posting the output of `dput()` somewhere publicly accessible (self-contained example is preferable, but reproducible is better than non-reproducible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question: To define the factors, `Effects` uses

```
nice(seq(min(var), max(var), length.out=5))
```

where nice is defined like so ([from here](https://github.com/cran/effects/blob/master/R/utilities.R)):

```
nice <- function (x, direction = c("round", "down", "up"), lead.digits = 1) {
  direction <- match.arg(direction)
  if (length(x) > 1){
    result <- sapply(x, nice, direction = direction, lead.digits = lead.digits)
    if (anyDuplicated(result)) result <- nice(x, direction=direction, lead.digits = lead.digits + 1)
    return(result)
  }
  if (x == 0) 
    return(0)
  power.10 <- floor(log(abs(x), 10))
  if (lead.digits > 1) 
    power.10 <- power.10 - lead.digits + 1
  lead.digit <- switch(direction, round = round(abs(x)/10^power.10), 
                       down = floor(abs(x)/10^power.10), up = ceiling(abs(x)/10^power.10))
  sign(x) * lead.digit * 10^power.10
}
```

An example of using it:

```
library(effects)

set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(100)
z = rexp(100)
y = factor(sample(1:2, 100, replace=T))

test = glm(y~x+z+x*z, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

preddat <- matrix('', 25, 100)
preddat <- expand.grid(nice(seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=5)), nice(seq(min(z), max(z), length.out=5)))
colnames(preddat) <- c("x", "z")
predicts <- predict(test, preddat, type = "response")
dim(predicts) <- c(5,5)

effectspred <- pnorm(effect("x:z", test)$fit)
dim(effectspred) <- c(5,5)

all.equal(effectspred, predicts)

[1] TRUE
```

This is straight forward to use with ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)

predicts %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  gather() %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = rep(nice(seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=5)), 5), y = value, color=key))
```

And regarding question 2, an intuitive way to think about it might be that, since the mean of Yhat doesn't change (predicted with fixed z), all the standard normal CDFs of the partial effects share the same intersection. E.g.

```
sapply(seq(0, 5, length.out = 15), function(k) {
  predict(test, data.frame(x = seq(-20, 20, length.out = 200), z = k), type = "response")}) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% gather() %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = rep(seq(-20, 20, length.out = 200), 15), y = value, color = key))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a truly great answer! Just one question, do you know how I can manually define the `factors` within `effects`?

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question, I figured it out myself in case someone faces a similar issue:
By adding `xlevels = list(varP = c(10, 40, 80)` to the `effect` specification, one can define the factor values.