# Anonymize data for each distinct row in R

Tags: r, paste, anonymize

Example

Value

```
15   
15   
15   
4   
37   
37   
37
```

There's three distinct values but 7 rows, below is what I want. Since I want to Anonymize my data. I keep getting the error "replacement has 3 rows, data has 7"

This is the code I'm using

```
final_df$Value <- paste("Value",seq(1:length(unique(final_df$Value))))
```

Value

```
Value 1
Value 1   
Value 1   
Value 2   
Value 3   
Value 3   
Value 3
```

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SciencesPo/versions/1.4.1/topics/Anonymize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454973/how-to-create-example-data-set-from-private-data-replacing-variable-names-and-l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create function that does the job:

```
anon <- function(x) {
    rl <- rle(x)$lengths
    ans<- paste("Value", rep(seq_along(rl), rl))
    return(ans)
}
```

call function:

```
anon(final_df$Value)
```

result:

```
# [1] "Value 1" "Value 1" "Value 1" "Value 2" "Value 3" "Value 3" "Value 3"
```

generalization:

```
df1 <- mtcars
df1[] <- lapply(df1, anon)
names(df1)    <- paste0("V", seq_along(names(df1)))
rownames(df1) <- NULL

df1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works great for columns that have values that are repeating in order. But how would this be done for a column where the values are not directly next to each other, and spread out?

Comment: Thats much easier. Just convert to factor and then to integer.